# Passport Local Strategy- Custom Callback for Single Page App

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm new to Node, and I'm building a single page web app. I'm using Express and Mongoose, trying to set up a login call like in [these docs.](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) It's possible I've completely got the wrong end of the stick so apologies.

In this first , I'm listening for login posts. This is where I'd like to add custom data to the response depending on if it's authenticated or not. [The documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) I mentioned has `res` passed in as a parameter, but I see no way to access it. Also, should the first parameter be "`err`" (and usually null)? The `.catch` statement in my promise further down needs to call `done()` or the request doesn't complete.

```
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local-signin', 
    function(req, res) {
        // wasn't sure what I should be doing here
    }
  ));
```

Passport setup:

```
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy(
{passReqToCallback : true}, 
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    funct.localAuth(username, password)
    .then(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log("LOGGED IN AS: " + user.username);
        done(null, user);
      }
      if (!user) {
        done(null, false);
      }
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      console.error(err.message);
      done(err);
    });
  }
));
```

And the authentication handler:

```
exports.localAuth = function (username, password) {

   return db.User.findOne({ username: username }).exec()
   .then(function (result){
      if(result){
         var hash = result._doc.passwordHash;

         if(!hash){
            console.warn("User " + username + " has no password set");
            return null;
         }
         console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash));
         if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash)) {
            return result;
         } else {
            return null;
         }
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   },
      function(reason){
         console.error("Failed to login: " + reason);
      }
   );
};
```

Comment: What does this print: `console.log("LOGGED IN AS: " + user.username);`? Also you said `// res isn't res! res is the `. Res is the what?

Comment: This line looks to be your problem: `return db.User.findOne({ username: username }).exec()`

This doesn't return what you think it does because `findOne` returns a promise, and once it's executed node is already on to the next job and doesn't come back to see what that promise has resolved until the next event loop (next tick).

Answer (score 0):

Again, I think the main problem you're facing is in:

```
 funct.localAuth(username, password)
.then(function (user) {
```

and

```
return db.User.findOne({ username: username }).exec()
.then(function (result){
```

The problem is that Node is already onto the next thing before it has a chance to be returned. Log out something after this and you'll see it's logged before the `findOne` resolves the user.

```
function logUser() {
  db.User.findOne({ username: username }).exec()
    .then(function (user) {

      console.log('this will log second', user)
    })

  console.log('this will log first')
}
```

Here's how I basically have passport set up in my project:

> auth/index.js

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback : true }, function (req, username, password, done) {

  db.User.findOne({ username: username }).exec()
    .then(function (user) {

      // It's a security thing to not let the user (potential hacker) to know whether a user exists
      // in the system or not, or if the email was wrong, or just the password, send them a generic error.
      if (!user)
        return done('Could not log you in with that email and password combination.', false)

      account.validatePassword(password)
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log(result) // The bcrypt result
          done(null, user)
        }, function (err) {
          console.error('Could not validate password', err)
          done(err, false)
        })

    }, function (err) {
        console.error('Could not find user', err)
    })

}))


module.exports = passport
```

Now you can use the auth module elsewhere (such as middleware) as well as add other strategies (such as bearer).

> models/user.js

```
userSchema.methods.validatePassword = function (password) {
  var user = this

  // This is how you properly return a promise.
  // Notice I'm either resolving or rejecting, not returning the result inside the function (I'm only using `return` so it exits the function early.)
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash, function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        return reject(err)

      if (!result)
        return reject('Could not log you in with that email and password combination.')

      resolve(result)
    })
  })
}
```

> middleware/local-auth.js

```
var passport = require('../auth')

module.exports = passport.authenticate('local-auth')
```

> router/routes/users.js

```
var localAuth = require('../../middleware/local-auth')

router.post('/login', localAuth, login)
// Other routes...

return router


function login(req, res) {
  // You have have a req.user
  res.send(req.user)
}
```

> router/index.js (this may be a little overboard, but I want to provide a real-world solution)

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'))
  // Other endpoints...
}
```

> server.js

```
require('./middleware/express')(app)
require('./router')(app)
```

### As for the `done()` business:

The `done()` callback takes in two parameters: an error, the user.
Somewhere in Passport it receives the arguments you passed with this syntax:

```
function (err, user) { }
```

This is a Node.js standard that the community adopted to bring order to callbacks because before promises or generators, callbacks were "the thing" and people were sometimes putting it as the last parameter or even somewhere in the middle. It's always the first now. You may see it called `next()` as well, it's the same thing. Change it to `next()` or `moveItAlong()` if you want, it will execute as it did before. Just use `next()` in your code so that it makes sense to others.

So when you pass `done(null, user)` it simply means that there is no error and in Passport, when the callback handler checks for the error, nothing is there and it proceeds. If you don't invoke the callback (`done()`) then nothing happens. Passport never receives the error or the user because you never invoked the callback; this is why you need to call `done()` in your `.catch()` also.